# Converting a spark dataframe into SQL scripts where I can Insert into Oracle database

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have requirement to save my resultant spark sql dataframe to Oracle table.
For which I need to use the Update scripts so that I can go and update the corresponding records in Oracle table.
I knew that the primary key column in Oracle table is only column 'c1' which is first column in my dataframe.

`val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 10,"a"), (2,20,"b"), (3, 30,"c"),(4, 40,"d"),(5, 50,"e"),(6, 60,"f"))).toDF("c1","c2","c3")`

df.show()

`+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
|  1| 10|  a|
|  2| 20|  b|
|  3| 30|  c|
|  4| 40|  d|
|  5| 50|  e|
|  6| 60|  f|
+---+---+---+`

So since I have 6 records in the dataframe I need to generate 6 Update scripts like below.

`UPDATE Oracle_table_name SET c2 = 10,c3='a' WHERE c1 =1`
And similarly for c1 = 2,3,4,5,6.

Note - I knew that all these c1(values 1 to 6) are already existing in Oracle table, so that is the reason I want to only generate 'Update' Statements.

How can i implement this ?

Comment: `UPDATE Oracle_table_name SET c2 = 10,c3='a' WHERE c1 =1;`  Similarly for c1 = 2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: Looks like I need to write a custom function where I need to iterate through each record in dataframe and build the 'Update' sql query.